# Publish XLS document that has visual basic code to a web site

Tags: microsoft-excel, webpage, visual-basic, xls

I have a requirement that was asked of me. We have an Excel document that has visual basic code attached to it and it does some computing. The user wants to publish this document onto an intranet site.

I tried the method of doing a Save-As with html but it does not allow me to publish the fully interactive document. The drop down controls are not active (just a snapshot picture).

Answer (score 0):

Publishing Excel files for viewing in web browsers is possible, but you will not have the full Excel functionality. VBA for UDFs should work, but any other VBA will not.

What version of Excel are you working with?

Saving as HTML will not give you any interactivity, just a table with constants. To interact with Excel files, use Office Web Apps or store the file on Skydrive. Skydrive is a free service from Microsoft, which currently offers 7GB storage. A document can be made public and the service will generate html code to embed a document that is stored on Skydrive into any web page. This embedded file will not have the full Excel functionality, though, i.e. no VBA, no data validation.